# Number of elements of a set: is my phrasing correct?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let $p$ be a prime number and let $A = \{k : k\in\Bbb Z^+, 1\le k\le p\}$. 
I create a set called $B$ that contains every $(k,k+2)$ number pair.
$B = \{(k, k+2), k\in A\}$
I want to define the number of elements in $A$ and in $B$, using $k$.
For example if $p=5$, then $A = \{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and $B=\{(1,3),(2,4),(3,5),(4,6),(5,7)\}$.
I want to say that $A$ has $p$ elements and $B$ has $p$ elements.

Is 
$|A|$ = $p$, because $k$ ∈ $Z^+$, 1≤k≤p 
 $|B|$ = $p$, because $k$ ∈ $Z^+$, 1≤k≤p
 mathematically correct, or if not, how should I formulate it?

Comment: To be totally rigourous, you should check that for two different values of $k$, you get two *different* elements in each of your set... (Think of a stupid example : if you define $C=\lbrace k-k, k\in A\rbrace$, of course $C$ has just one element, even if it is indexed by $p$ values of $k$...)

Comment: I understand your point in your example, but every $k$ in $A$ are distinct elements, therefore every $(k,k+2)$ in $B$ are also distinct, aren't they?

Comment: In your example you say that 1-1=0, 2-2=0, 3-3=0, etc. In my case there is no mathematical operation.

Comment: Yeah, in your case, it is almost clear ! Precising it as you did in your comment ("every k in A are distinct elements, therefore every (k,k+2) in B are also distinct") would be enough to make your agument undestructible :)